# ¿Cómo filtro objetos de una lista para que no aparezcan más?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando eliminar objetos aleatorios de una lista.
Lo que quiero hacer es eliminar los objetos aleatorios de la lista y que la lista vaya disminuyendo, pero no disminuye, si no que, con cada iteración se eliminan solo en esa iteración.
La cosa es que el método filtrar sólo filtra cada vez que itera, pero no me lo elimina completamente.
¿Alguien sabe cómo podría gestionarlo?

JSON:

```
[
    {"nombre":"Angel"},
    {"nombre":"Eduardo"},
    {"nombre":"Fatima"},
    {"nombre":"Lucia S."},
    {"nombre":"Lucia"},
    {"nombre":"Juan"},
    {"nombre":"Pablo"},
    {"nombre":"Arturo"},
    {"nombre":"Victor"},
    {"nombre":"Francisco"},
    {"nombre":"Israel"},
    {"nombre":"Ivan"}
]
```

CODIGO:

```
const jsonData = require('./Nombres.json');
let jsonDataObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
let contador=0;
let newArray=jsonDataObj;
if(newArray.length%2==0){
    while(contador<newArray.length){
    const aleatorio1 = newArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * newArray.length)];
    const aleatorio2 = newArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * newArray.length)];
    if(aleatorio1.nombre!==aleatorio2.nombre)
    console.log(aleatorio1,aleatorio2);
    newArray = jsonDataObj
                .filter((el)=>el!==aleatorio1)
                .filter((el)=>el!==aleatorio2)
     contador++;
     console.log(newArray);
    }
}
else{
    console.log("Intentálo de nuevo");
}
```

Comment: Cada iteración los elementos regresan, porque estás importando un Json a una variable, no estás haciendo referencia a el json en sí, así que cada que la iteración corre, debes sobreescribir ese json con tu nuevo arreglo

Comment: como podría hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Podría hacerlo sin sobreescribir el json?

Answer (score 2):

La razón por la que sólo se elimina en la iteración es porque estás filtrando x valor en cada iteración sin actualizar el valor del arreglo. Pero no estás actualizando el valor del mismo.

```
jsonDataObj= jsonDataObj
                .filter((el)=>el!==aleatorio1)
                .filter((el)=>el!==aleatorio2)  
newArray = jsonDataObj

console.log(newArray )
```